# is there a Google API for adding verified domain for webhooks?

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, webhooks

I am able to automate domain verification for push notifications for google drive/calendar (which is Google SiteVerification API). Now I want to automate how to register the verified domain in `Google Cloud Console -> API Manager -> Credentials -> Domain Verification`. I am searching for the available APIs but no luck. Is there a way to do this?

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvmoq.png)

Thank you so much!